# Converting a struct pointer to char pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I working on one program where we are trying to convert a struct pointer to a char pointer so it can be used later in some other function, i heard someone say that, if the elements of the struct are aligned, then we can do this typecast and work on it but need help in understanding this concept:

Example:

```
Structure S1{
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    uint16_t first_len;
    uint16_t last_len;
    uint32_t attrs;
    op status; -> this is a enum
};

Structure S2{
uint16_t a;
uint16_t b;
uint32_t c;
int8_t d; 
};
```

S2 can be converted to char* but S1 can't.

Below is a program where i want to use(this is for deeping copying one structure contents to another), but i am getting segmentation fault for this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> 

#define ARW_SIZE 3

typedef struct sample_struct{
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    int first_len;
    int last_len;
    int attrs;
    int status;
}sample;

typedef struct sample_header{
    int first_len;
    int last_len;
    int attrs;
}header;

int copy(sample *src, char *dst){
    header *header_ptr = (header *)dst;

    header_ptr->first_len = src->first_len;
    header_ptr->last_len = src->last_len;
    header_ptr->attrs = src->attrs;
    dst += sizeof(header);
    memmove(dst, src->first_name, src->first_len);

    if (header_ptr->last_len) {
        dst += src->last_len;
        memmove(dst, src->last_name, src->last_len);
    }

    return sizeof(header) + header_ptr->first_len + header_ptr->last_len;
}

int func1(sample **arw){
    sample *s1 = malloc(sizeof(sample));
    s1->first_name = malloc(sizeof(char));
    s1->last_name = malloc(sizeof(char));
    s1->first_name = "sai";
    s1->last_name = "sankalp";
    s1->first_len = 3;
    s1->last_len = 8;
    s1->attrs = 6;
    s1->status = 1;

    sample *s2 = malloc(sizeof(sample));
    s2->first_name = malloc(sizeof(char));
    s2->last_name = malloc(sizeof(char));
    s2->first_name = "sai1";
    s2->last_name = "sankalp1";
    s2->first_len = 4;
    s2->last_len = 9;
    s2->attrs = 64;
    s2->status = 12;

    *arw = malloc(sizeof(sample) * ARW_SIZE);

    arw += copy(s1, (char *)*arw);
    
    return 1;


}

int main(){

    printf("Hello World!\n");


    sample *res = NULL;

    func1(&res);
   
    printf("Fname: %s, Lname: %s, Fname_Len: %d, Lname_Len: %d, attrs: %d, status: %d\n", res->first_name, res->last_name, res->first_len, res->last_len, res->status);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why do you need to convert the structure? Why do you think that would solve the original problem? And what do you men when you say that `S1` "can't" be converted?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, i can't tell u the actual code, but i have edited my post with a similar program. By S1 can't be converted i meant, i was getting segmentation fault

Comment: A pointer is not a string... Copying 4 bytes (the first name) is NOT copying the string pointed to by the source...

Comment: Please note that your structure contains pointers, not the actual data they point to. No matter what you do, when you copy the structure you only copy the pointers themselves and not the data they point to. If you for example transfer this structure over the network or save it to a file, you only transfer or save the pointers themselves. Using those pointers in another process will lead to *undefined behavior*. And again, what is the *problem* you want to solve? The code doesn't matter, but please tell us the actual and underlying problem you want to solve.

Comment: The problem i am trying to solve is: i need to do a deep copy of a structure that has pointers to characters. Why i want to do deep copy is that: an array of structures may get freed at some point but i don’t want to lose the information so i need to copy that array of structures to another array of structures

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're referring to is related to structure padding and alignment in C. When you have a struct, the compiler might insert padding between the members to align them in memory. This padding ensures that each member starts at an address that is a multiple of its size, which can improve the performance of memory access.

Now, the issue with converting a struct pointer to a char pointer and vice versa is related to this padding. If there is padding between the members of a struct, then the size of the struct might be larger than the sum of the sizes of its members. This padding is added by the compiler for alignment purposes.

In your example:

```
struct S1 {
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    uint16_t first_len;
    uint16_t last_len;
    uint32_t attrs;
    enum op status;
};

struct S2 {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint32_t c;
    int8_t d; 
};
```

The `S1` struct contains pointers `(char*)` and a `32-bit integer (uint32_t)`, which might result in padding between members due to alignment requirements. The `S2` struct, on the other hand, consists of members with sizes that align naturally without requiring additional padding.

To convert a struct pointer to a char pointer and vice versa, you generally would use the concept of "type punning." However, doing this with a struct that contains pointers and potentially has padding requires caution. You might encounter issues if the struct contains non-trivial types or if the layout is not what you expect.

If you need to serialize/deserialize a struct for communication or storage purposes, consider using proper serialization techniques or libraries. Also, if you need to ensure a specific memory layout, you can use compiler-specific directives to control packing and alignment .your added program has some issues related to Memory Allocation for strings
so Instead of using `malloc(sizeof(char))` for string allocation, use `malloc(strlen(str) + 1)` to allocate enough space for the string and the null terminator.Use `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy strings instead of assigning them directly also The `copy` function should take the destination structure as an argument, not a `char*`.Now fixed code version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARW_SIZE 3

typedef struct sample_struct {
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    int first_len;
    int last_len;
    int attrs;
    int status;
} sample;

typedef struct sample_header {
    int first_len;
    int last_len;
    int attrs;
} header;

int copy(sample *src, sample *dst) {
    header *header_ptr = (header *)dst;

    header_ptr->first_len = src->first_len;
    header_ptr->last_len = src->last_len;
    header_ptr->attrs = src->attrs;

    dst->first_name = malloc(src->first_len + 1);
    strcpy(dst->first_name, src->first_name);

    if (header_ptr->last_len) {
        dst->last_name = malloc(src->last_len + 1);
        strcpy(dst->last_name, src->last_name);
    }

    return sizeof(header) + header_ptr->first_len + header_ptr->last_len;
}

int func1(sample **arw) {
    sample *s1 = malloc(sizeof(sample));
    s1->first_name = malloc(strlen("sai") + 1);
    strcpy(s1->first_name, "sai");
    s1->last_name = malloc(strlen("sankalp") + 1);
    strcpy(s1->last_name, "sankalp");
    s1->first_len = 3;
    s1->last_len = 8;
    s1->attrs = 6;
    s1->status = 1;

    sample *s2 = malloc(sizeof(sample));
    s2->first_name = malloc(strlen("sai1") + 1);
    strcpy(s2->first_name, "sai1");
    s2->last_name = malloc(strlen("sankalp1") + 1);
    strcpy(s2->last_name, "sankalp1");
    s2->first_len = 4;
    s2->last_len = 9;
    s2->attrs = 64;
    s2->status = 12;

    *arw = malloc(sizeof(sample) * ARW_SIZE);

    arw += copy(s1, *arw);

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    sample *res = NULL;

    func1(&res);

    printf(
        "Fname: %s, Lname: %s, Fname_Len: %d, Lname_Len: %d, attrs: %d, status: %d\n",
        res->first_name, res->last_name, res->first_len, res->last_len, res->attrs, res->status
    );

    // Free allocated memory
    free(res->first_name);
    free(res->last_name);
    free(res);

    return 0;
}
```

General Summery of the fixes:  memory allocation issues and string assignments improvements also freeing the allocated memory of course to prevent memory leaks that would happen

Answer (score 1):

The problem of deep copying is really unrelated to what seems to be your main question: Conversion of `struct S1 *` to `char *`.

That conversion isn't even needed.

The simple solution is just to allocate memory for both the structure and the strings, and copy both:

```
struct S1 *copy_S1(const struct S1 *original)
{
    // Allocate memory for the new structure
    struct S1 *copy = malloc(sizeof *copy);

    // Copy the structure
    *copy = *original;

    // Allocate memory for the strings
    copy->first_name = malloc(strlen(original->first_name) + 1);
    copy->last_name = malloc(strlen(original->last_name) + 1);

    // And copy the strings
    strcpy(copy->first_name, original->first_name);
    strcpy(copy->last_name, original->last_name);

    // And return the new structure
    return copy;
}
```

If your system have the `strdup` function it can be used to duplicate the strings.

Note that the above code, and the use of `strdup`, requires the strings to be proper null-terminated strings, like all string-handling in C.

If they are not null-terminated, and you have the length of them elsewhere in the structure (is it seem to be) then you use that value for the `malloc` call, and use `memcpy` to copy the strings.

---

The above solution creates a deep copy of the structure as-is, but it doesn't *serialize* it. The structure still can't be saved or transferred or used by another process.

That becomes much more complicated, and I recommend you try to find a serialization library which can help you with that.

**Unless** you already have a very specific format you need to match, in which case you need to do it manualy.

For that, allocate enough memory to hold both structures *and* both the strings. Copy (use `memcpy`, not `memmove`) the header to the beginning, but *don't* copy the other data-structure as a whole. Instead you need to match the actual format you're using, possibly by copying the individual members one by one. This copying can be done with pointer arithmetic, casting and plain assignment. Then copy (again using `memcpy`) the strings to their respective location.